# jQuery Clone - PDO Insert

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, insert

Could do with some help. So I've got an array like so.

1) I want insert the first 2 (invoice from and invoice to) in 'invoice' table 
2) The rest in 'invoice_item' table with last insert id from 'invoice'

I've got point 1 working and some of point 2, the only problem is it only insert 1 record from 'item_description' and 'item_qty' (Desc 2 and 2).

I know it's something to do with the array but am new'ish to PDO, PHP. Would appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [invoice_from] => Person 1
    [invoice_to] => Person 2
    [item_description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Desc 1
            [1] => Desc 2
        )

    [item_qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
)

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoice(invoice_from, invoice_to) VALUES(:invoice_from, :invoice_to)");         

$stmt->bindparam(':invoice_from', $invoice_from);

$stmt->bindparam(':invoice_to', $invoice_to);

$stmt->execute();           

$last_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoices_items(invoice_id, item_description, item_qty) VALUES(:invoice_id, :item_description, :item_qty)");         

$stmt->bindparam(':invoice_id', $last_id);

foreach($item_description as $val_1)
{
    $stmt->bindparam(':item_description', $val_1);
}

foreach($item_qty as $val_2)
{
    $stmt->bindparam(':item_qty', $val_2);
}

$stmt->execute();
```